# Viewport always follows div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a little web project where you can move a div with your arrow keys. I used jQuery for this:

**html**

```
<div id="machine" style="width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: darkgrey; position: absolute;">
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
var pressed = false;

$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if (!pressed) {
        width = $(this).width();
        height = $(this).height();
        switch (e.which) {
            case 37:
                $('#machine').stop().animate({
                    left: '-=' + width
                }, 2000); //left arrow key
                break;
            case 39:
                $('#machine').stop().animate({
                    left: '+=' + width
                }, 2000); //right arrow key
                break;
        }
    }
    pressed = true;

}).keyup(function() {
    $('#machine').stop();
    pressed = false;
});
```

Now I want that the viewport always follows this div `#machine`.

So when this div moves out of the viewport at the right, the viewport scrolls to right. But stops, if the div stops.

Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: edit question and add html

Comment: Do you need more infos or so?